# Csv Parsing -Reading Data between Parantheses

Tags: csv

I am a little stuck here , Need some advice please ,I have converted the csv file from blob to string and i have divided the file into columns successfully and put them into values ,

But i now further need to process my data ,Please see below .

String strc1='';
strc1=values.get(5);

strc1 contains values in the format:

Martin, Haene; (ABCD);Michi, Koerner; (DEF)

I only want to read the values inside parantheses, I cant think of a way to do that , I ve looked into trim , replace , remove ,split functions for the string , but nothing seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Pattern and Matcher classes to find values in a string:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile('\\((.+?)\\)');
Matcher m = p.matcher(stringValue);
while(m.find()) {
    String theMatch = m.group(1);
}
```

What you do with theMatch is up to you.

Comment: Thank you for your response , I am very new to regex, I am sorry for asking very basic stuff , Can you please confirm if this is the regex pattern equivalent to round bracket() , i just tried using it and it gave me Illegal character sequence error. What i am trying to do here is                        String strc1='';                                                                     
  strc1=values.get(5);
strc1 contains values in the format:
Martin, Haene; (ABCD);Michi, Koerner; (DEF) . I want to remove all text except for the one inside the bracket which is ABCD; DEF .

Comment: @Natasha I was missing some characters. Look at my updated answer. The other solution should probably work as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the function replaceAll.

> replaceAll(regExp, replacement)
>
> Replaces each substring of a string that matches the regular
>   expression regExp with the replacement sequence replacement.

An example:

```
String s1 = '(ABCD)';
String s2 = s1.replaceAll('[()]', '');
system.debug(s2);
```

The result should be *ABCD*

Hope this helps